# Django bulk_create() with models' fields having custom validators

Tags: django, validation, bulk-create

In my Django application, I am using `bulk_create()`. For one of the fields in a target model I have assigned a set of validators to restrict the allowed value to uppercase letters (alphabets) and to a *fixed* length of "3", as shown below:

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    plant = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=4, ...
    plant_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, ...
    plant_short_name = models.CharField(max_length=3, validators=[...
    # rest of the fields ...
```

I am restricting field `plant_short_name` to something like **CHT** for say, *Plant Charlotte*.

Using the source file (.csv) I am able to successfully create new instances using `bulk_create`, however I find that the data get saved even with field `plant_short_name`'s value being different.

For example, if I use the source as:

```
plant,plant_name,plant_short_name
9999,XYZ Plant,XY
```

the new instance still gets created although the length of (string) value of field `plant_short_name` is **only** 2 (instead of 3 as defined in the validators).

If I am to use an online `create` function (say, Django `CreateView`), the validators work as expected.

**How do I control / rstrict the creation of model instance when a field value of incorrect length is used in the source file?**

Comment: I doubt validators work for bulk_create( am not sure), anyway model save method won't work for bulk_create. Put some logs in the custom validator and check whether its calling

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31384

Comment: @Jisson It does not. Anyway, I was going through Django docs trying to find out if I may capture the validators somehow (something like `_meta` values for model fields). Not sure though. Can you please come back on this?

Answer (score 0):

[bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

> This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in
> an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many
> objects there are). Also, does *not* call save() on each of the
> instances, do not send any pre/post_save signals.

By `efficient manner` it means there is no validation. You can explore more of the function code in `django/models/db/query.py` inside the environment.

Comment: Thanks. In my query, I have pointed out that I am using `custom` validators for restricting the minimum length of the field to **three (3)**, that it should accept only letters, and that all the letters must be `uppercase` only (besides specifically restricting maximum lenght using `max_length=3`). And while creating new instance/s using Django CBV `CreateView`, the validators are working just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have misinterpreted your question. As described in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), `bulk_create()`comes with a number of caveats, if its not validating properly it means that is creating every object without calling `.full_clean()` apparently. Which means that will also save `plant` field with more than four chars.